# Symfony2 Get File Object as PHP Native $_FILE

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I can get the file object like this:

```
$request->files->get('file')
```

But i have to give my uploader php native file (`$_FILES['file']`).

Is there any way to get the native file from request object?

Symfony var_dump (xdebug html output):

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>object</b>(<i>Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile</i>)[<i>13</i>]
  <i>private</i> 'test' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>boolean</small> <font color='#75507b'>false</font>
  <i>private</i> 'originalName' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'slide-3.jpg'</font> <i>(length=11)</i>
  <i>private</i> 'mimeType' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'image/jpeg'</font> <i>(length=10)</i>
  <i>private</i> 'size' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>147845</font>
  <i>private</i> 'error' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>0</font>
</pre>
```

Comment: Why do you **have** to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the HttpFoundations FileBag, 
https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/FileBag.php

all files are converted into UploadedFile classes, this class has all the informations a native php $_FILES['file'] has.

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile
```

If you still want to use the $_FILES['file'], you can simply use the superglobals, the are still available.
The Request just wraps the Superglobals to abstract them in an object oriented way